# Is there a way to reference multiple variables for a conditional in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

For example, if a case that looks something like this:

```
distance_11 = 5
distance_12 = 3
distance_13 = 2

if distance_* == 3:
    distance_* = [1,2,3]
```

I know that code is obviously incorrect, but I'm attempting to display what I'm trying to do. Search a set of variables with similar names, and then if one meets that condition, assign it to a specified array. I know I could technical write an elif condition for each specific variable, but in the actual use case there are a lot more variables. Any form of help would be appreciated- thank you.

Comment: Why is `distance` not an array? Or (even better) a `set`?

Comment: In python, “Array” => list

Answer (score 3):

You should make distances into a list or array like this:

```
distances = [5, 3, 2]

for (i, val) in enumerate(distances):
    if val == 3:
        distances[i] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a solution like this.

```
distance_11 = 5
distance_12 = 3
distance_13 = 2
dists = [distance_11, distance_12, distance_13]

for i in range(len(dists)):
    if dists[i] == 3:
        dists[i] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely be using an array as [@Eric M mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61261001/#61261034).
But if you cannot change the variable names, you can use Python's `globals` builtin.

```
from fnmatch import filter    

distance_11 = 5
distance_12 = 3
distance_13 = 2

for var_name in filter(globals().keys(), 'distance_*'):
    if globals()[var_name] == 3:
        globals()[var_name] = [1, 2, 3]
```

If the `distance_*` variables aren't global, also look into the [`locals()` built-in](https://thepythonguru.com/python-builtin-functions/locals/)

Answer (score -1):

You could use `vars` to achieve that

```py
distance_11 = 5
distance_12 = 3
distance_13 = 2

for i in range(11, 14):
    varName = f'distance_{i}'
    if vars()[varName] == 3:
        vars()[varName] = [1,2,3]
```